# Extjs 4 creating form instance

Tags: forms, extjs4, instance

i'm new to extjs 4.

I have to use same from in different events

Creating a chapter and 
Editing a created chapter

In both the situations all form fields are same

Is it better to use different forms for both the situations or can i use the same form instance in two places.

present i'm doing as follows

```
 buttons: [{
            text: 'Save',
            handler: function () {
                    var cform = chapter_form.getForm(); 
                    cform.submit({                     
                        url: BASE_URL+'courses/chapters/saveChapter',
                        waitMsg:'Saving Data...',

                        success: function (res, req) {

                             cform.reset();
                             win2.destroy();    

                        },
                        failure:function(form, action) {

                        }
                    });

            }
        },{
            text: 'Update',
            handler: function(){
                var cuform = chapter_form.getForm();                                            
                cuform.submit({                    
                    url: BASE_URL+'courses/chapters/updateCourseChapter/'+chp_id,
                    waitMsg:'Saving Data...',

                    success: function (res, req) {

                     cuform.reset();


                    },
                    failure:function(form, action) {

                    }
                });

            }

        }, {
            text: 'Cancel',
            handler: function () {
                win2.destroy();
            }

        }]
```

Whats the better way to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggested use the same form for both actions. I usually do not separate update and create server actions. I have a general save action.

On server I check the posted model. If it has Id property set - it means that I should updated entity, otherwise I should create it. You could use ExtJs hidden form field to store the model id.